# Are there any numerically stable versions of the centroid finding algorithm for polygons?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, numeric

Say I have an almost degenerate 2-D polygon such as:

`[[40.802,9.289],[40.875,9.394],[40.910000000000004,9.445],[40.911,9.446],[40.802,9.289]]`

For reference this looks like:

[image]

If I use the standard centroid algorithm as shown [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_polygon), for example this python code:

```py
pts = [[40.802,9.289],[40.875,9.394],[40.910000000000004,9.445], [40.911,9.446],[40.802,9.289]]
a = 0.0
c = [0.0, 0.0]
for i in range(0,4):
    k = pts[i][0] * pts[i + 1][1] - pts[i + 1][0] * pts[i][1]
    a += k
    c = [c[0] + k * (pts[i][0] + pts[i + 1][0]), c[1] + k * (pts[i][1] + pts[i + 1][1])]
c = [c[0] / (3 * a), c[1] / (3 * a)]
```

I get `c = [-10133071.666666666, -14636692.583333334]`. In other cases where `a == 0.0` I might also get a divide by zero.

What I would ideally like is that in the worst case, the centroid is equal to one of the vertices or somewhere within the polygon, and that no arbitrary tolerances should be used for avoiding this situation. Is there some clever way to rewrite the equation to make it more numerically stable?

Comment: One simple thing you could try is moving the entire polygon to the origin (i.e. subtract the corners` mean). This would give you at least some more floating point precision.

Comment: Your program is wrong, `c` mustn't be multiplied by `k`. (But after fixing, the numerical instability remains.)

Comment: @NicoSchertler: I don't think this helps, the problem is the area close to zero.

Comment: Another common approach would be avoiding the divisions and using homogeneous coordinates instead. In such a setup, you'd get a result which is close to the null vector, which does not represent a point. The homogeneous coordinates of the origin are (0, 0, 1) or any multiple thereof. This helps if you can continue without a division, but it just gives you a different representation for “this centroid is not defined”, not a point inside the polygon as you expected, so I'm just posting this as a comment.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Agreed that this is not a guaranteed solution (that's why it is only a comment). However, the increased accuracy near the origin *may* be just enough to represent the near-zero area.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks, I fixed the code.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Gerard Bashein and Paul R. Detmer wrote in the book *Graphics Gems IV*: *The loss of numerical accuracy due to the
remaining subtraction can be reduced if, before calculating the centroid, the coordinate
system is translated to place its origin somewhere close to the polygon.*

Comment: You say "What I would ideally like is that in the worst case, the centroid is equal to one of the vertices or somewhere within the polygon,"   Do you mean to prepend the condition "if the polygon is convex"?  Or do you mean "within the convex hull of the vertices"?

Comment: @Don yes I suppose that is true for centroids in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the area is zero (or very close to zero, if you cannot afford to do exact arithmetic), probably the best option is to take perimeter centroid of the set of points.

Perimeter centroid is given by the ratio of the weighted sum of midpoints of each side of the polygon (the weight is the length of the corresponding side), to the perimeter of the polygon.

Using exact arithmetic, it is possible to calculate the centroid in this case.
[image: centroid vs perimeter centroid]
*red point is the perimeter centroid and the green one is the true centroid*

I used sage to calculate the centroid exactly https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/f3149cab-2b4b-494a-b795-06d62ae133dd/files/2016-08-17-102024.sagews.

People have been looking for a way to relate these points with respect to each other -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173903/centroids-of-a-polygon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this formula can be easily made more stable towards nearly degenerated 2D polygons. The problem is that the calculation of the area (A) relies on subtracting trapezoidal shapes (see [Paul Bourke](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonmesh/)). For very small areas you inevitably run into the numerical precision.

I see two possible solutions:

**1.)** You could check the area and if it gets below a threshold assume the polygon is degenerated and just take the mean of minimal and maximal x and y values (the middle of the line)

**2.).** Use floating point arithmetics with higher precision, maybe something like [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/).

Btw. you have a mistake in your code. It should be:

```
c = [c[0] + k * (pts[i][0] + pts[i + 1][0]), c[1] + k * (pts[i][1] + pts[i + 1][1])]
```

However that doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the [following](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/Code/centroid.c) is an authoritative C implementation for the computation of the centroid of a *simple* polygon, it is written by [Joseph O'Rourke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387778/joseph-orourke), author of the book *Computational Geometry in C*.

```
/*
    Written by Joseph O'Rourke
    orourke@cs.smith.edu
    October 27, 1995

    Computes the centroid (center of gravity) of an arbitrary
    simple polygon via a weighted sum of signed triangle areas,
    weighted by the centroid of each triangle.
    Reads x,y coordinates from stdin.  
    NB: Assumes points are entered in ccw order!  
    E.g., input for square:
        0   0
        10  0
        10  10
        0   10
    This solves Exercise 12, p.47, of my text,
    Computational Geometry in C.  See the book for an explanation
    of why this works. Follow links from
        http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/

*/
#include    <stdio.h>

#define DIM     2               /* Dimension of points */
typedef int     tPointi[DIM];   /* type integer point */
typedef double  tPointd[DIM];   /* type double point */

#define PMAX    1000            /* Max # of pts in polygon */
typedef tPointi tPolygoni[PMAX];/* type integer polygon */

int     Area2( tPointi a, tPointi b, tPointi c );
void    FindCG( int n, tPolygoni P, tPointd CG );
int ReadPoints( tPolygoni P );
void    Centroid3( tPointi p1, tPointi p2, tPointi p3, tPointi c );
void    PrintPoint( tPointd p );

int main()
{
    int n;
    tPolygoni   P;
    tPointd CG;

    n = ReadPoints( P );
    FindCG( n, P ,CG);
    printf("The cg is ");
    PrintPoint( CG );
}

/* 
        Returns twice the signed area of the triangle determined by a,b,c,
        positive if a,b,c are oriented ccw, and negative if cw.
*/
int     Area2( tPointi a, tPointi b, tPointi c )
{
    return
        (b[0] - a[0]) * (c[1] - a[1]) -
        (c[0] - a[0]) * (b[1] - a[1]);
}

/*      
        Returns the cg in CG.  Computes the weighted sum of
    each triangle's area times its centroid.  Twice area
    and three times centroid is used to avoid division
    until the last moment.
*/
void     FindCG( int n, tPolygoni P, tPointd CG)
{
        int     i;
        double  A2, Areasum2 = 0;        /* Partial area sum */    
    tPointi Cent3;

    CG[0] = 0;
    CG[1] = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < n-1; i++) {
            Centroid3( P[0], P[i], P[i+1], Cent3 );
            A2 =  Area2( P[0], P[i], P[i+1]);
        CG[0] += A2 * Cent3[0];
        CG[1] += A2 * Cent3[1];
        Areasum2 += A2;
          }
        CG[0] /= 3 * Areasum2;
        CG[1] /= 3 * Areasum2;
    return;
}
/*
    Returns three times the centroid.  The factor of 3 is
    left in to permit division to be avoided until later.
*/
void    Centroid3( tPointi p1, tPointi p2, tPointi p3, tPointi c )
{
        c[0] = p1[0] + p2[0] + p3[0];
        c[1] = p1[1] + p2[1] + p3[1];
    return;
}

void    PrintPoint( tPointd p )
{
        int i;

        putchar('(');
        for ( i=0; i<DIM; i++) {
        printf("%f",p[i]);
        if (i != DIM - 1) putchar(',');
        }
        putchar(')');
    putchar('\n');
}

/*
    Reads in the coordinates of the vertices of a polygon from stdin,
    puts them into P, and returns n, the number of vertices.
    The input is assumed to be pairs of whitespace-separated coordinates,
    one pair per line.  The number of points is not part of the input.
*/
int  ReadPoints( tPolygoni P )
{
    int n = 0;

    printf("Polygon:\n");
    printf("  i   x   y\n");      
    while ( (n < PMAX) && 
        (scanf("%d %d",&P[n][0],&P[n][1]) != EOF) ) {
    printf("%3d%4d%4d\n", n, P[n][0], P[n][1]);
    ++n;
    }
    if (n < PMAX)
    printf("n = %3d vertices read\n",n);
    else    printf("Error in ReadPoints:\too many points; max is %d\n", 
               PMAX);
    putchar('\n');

    return  n;
}
```

The code solves the Exercise 12 at page 47 of the first edition of the book, a brief explanation is [here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/graphics/algorithms-faq/):

> Subject 2.02: How can the centroid of a polygon be computed?
>
> ```
> The centroid (a.k.a. the center of mass, or center of gravity)
> of a polygon can be computed as the weighted sum of the centroids
> of a partition of the polygon into triangles.  The centroid of a
> triangle is simply the average of its three vertices, i.e., it
> has coordinates (x1 + x2 + x3)/3 and (y1 + y2 + y3)/3.  This 
> suggests first triangulating the polygon, then forming a sum
> of the centroids of each triangle, weighted by the area of
> each triangle, the whole sum normalized by the total polygon area.
> This indeed works, but there is a simpler method:  the triangulation
> need not be a partition, but rather can use positively and
> negatively oriented triangles (with positive and negative areas),
> as is used when computing the area of a polygon.  This leads to
> a very simple algorithm for computing the centroid, based on a
> sum of triangle centroids weighted with their signed area.
> The triangles can be taken to be those formed by any fixed point,
> e.g., the vertex v0 of the polygon, and the two endpoints of 
> consecutive edges of the polygon: (v1,v2), (v2,v3), etc.  The area 
> of a triangle with vertices a, b, c is half of this expression:
>             (b[X] - a[X]) * (c[Y] - a[Y]) -
>             (c[X] - a[X]) * (b[Y] - a[Y]);
>
> Code available at ftp://cs.smith.edu/pub/code/centroid.c (3K).
> Reference: [Gems IV] pp.3-6; also includes code.
> ```

I did not study this algorithm, nor I tested it, but at a first glance it seems to me it is slightly different from the Wikipedia one.

The code from the book *Graphics Gems IV* is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20040223132019/http://www.acm.org/pubs/tog/GraphicsGems/gemsiv/centroid.c):

```
/*
 * ANSI C code from the article
 * "Centroid of a Polygon"
 * by Gerard Bashein and Paul R. Detmer,
    (gb@locke.hs.washington.edu, pdetmer@u.washington.edu)
 * in "Graphics Gems IV", Academic Press, 1994
 */

/*********************************************************************
polyCentroid: Calculates the centroid (xCentroid, yCentroid) and area
of a polygon, given its vertices (x[0], y[0]) ... (x[n-1], y[n-1]). It
is assumed that the contour is closed, i.e., that the vertex following
(x[n-1], y[n-1]) is (x[0], y[0]).  The algebraic sign of the area is
positive for counterclockwise ordering of vertices in x-y plane;
otherwise negative.

Returned values:  0 for normal execution;  1 if the polygon is
degenerate (number of vertices < 3);  and 2 if area = 0 (and the
centroid is undefined).
**********************************************************************/
int polyCentroid(double x[], double y[], int n,
         double *xCentroid, double *yCentroid, double *area)
     {
     register int i, j;
     double ai, atmp = 0, xtmp = 0, ytmp = 0;
     if (n < 3) return 1;
     for (i = n-1, j = 0; j < n; i = j, j++)
      {
      ai = x[i] * y[j] - x[j] * y[i];
      atmp += ai;
      xtmp += (x[j] + x[i]) * ai;
      ytmp += (y[j] + y[i]) * ai;
      }
     *area = atmp / 2;
     if (atmp != 0)
      {
      *xCentroid =  xtmp / (3 * atmp);
      *yCentroid =  ytmp / (3 * atmp);
      return 0;
      }
     return 2;
     }
```

CGAL allow you to use an exact multi-precision number type instead of `double` or `float` in order to get exact computations, it will cost an execution time overhead, the idea is decsribed in [The Exact Computation Paradigm](https://www.cgal.org/exact.html).

A [commercial implementation](https://www.mvtec.com/doc/halcon/1905/en/area_center_xld.html) claims to use the Green's theorem, I do not know whether it use a multi-precision number type:

> The area and centroid are computed by applying Green's theorem using
>   only the points on the contour or polygon

I think it refers to the Wikipedia algorithm since the formulae in Wikipedia are an application of the Green's theorem as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2002449/10799).